# Android Spinner issue - The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(NewSRO, int, String[]) is undefined

Tags: java, android

I am having a hell of a time with a spinner under PagerAdapter. Please take a look at provide any suggestions you might have. I am simply stump, might be too late at night.
I tried to wrap the code into separate class and then call the class with no success. Next I figured all I would need to do is add `getActivity()` from Fragment, this too I was having issues.

```
    public class NewSRO extends PagerAdapter {

    //---return the total number of pages---
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        int resId = 0;
        View view = null; // setting view variable with null value

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.layout.new_client_1;
            view  = inflater.inflate(resId, null); // inflating view to attach spinner data
            final Spinner s1_clients;
            final String[] clients = {
                    "client1",
                    "client2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                    };
              //---Spinner View---
              s1_clients = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_client_select);
              SpinnerAdapter new_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                      NewSRO.this,
                      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                      clients);           
              s1_clients.setAdapter(new_adapter);
              s1_clients.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, 
                  int arg2, long arg3) {
                      int index = s1_clients.getSelectedItemPosition(); Toast.makeText(null, "You have selected item : " + clients[index], 
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                  } 
              });


            break;
        case 1:
            resId = R.layout.new_client_1;
            break;
        case 2:
            resId = R.layout.new_client_1;
            break;
        }

        //View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened when you changed `NewSRO.this` with `getActivity()`?

Comment: use `ActivityName.this` instead of `NewSRO.this` or use this `collection.getContext()` coz you use the same to initialize your LayoutInflater

Comment: Thank you Raghunandan, that seems to get me past the initial error. However, now I am running into a "NullPointerException" with instantiatingItem for s1_clients.setAdapter(new_adapter);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first it seemed adding collection.getContext() was the right direction. Albeit, it just caused me to stop paying attention to the inflated View which was ultimately the problem. Each case statement needed a view to inflate, without it the application would crash.

Basically I needed add the following to each case statement:

```
view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
```

Then I needed to modify my SpinnerAdapter with view.getContext() :

```
  SpinnerAdapter new_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                  view.getContext(),
                  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                  clients);
```

I hope this will help someone else as viewPager is a great way to enhance your user interface.

Cheers, 
Brandy Lee Camacho